# How can we change the font type for a line in latex?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, report

Can someone help me how can I use different font just for one line in my `LaTeX` report in Acknowledgement?

My settings are:

```
documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=12.5pt,DIV15,BCOR20mm,oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
```

[image]

Kind regards,

Dipak

Comment: This has probably been answered here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249 See the list of links for the 'flavors of TeX' you're using.

Comment: Kind user no no :-( the green check it's not mine and it doesn't belong to me. I thank you but for my correctness it is right that you give it back to the previous user. I always wish you the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposal is to use two different font families (here I have used to compile `pdfLaTeX` instead of `XeLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX`). In the first version I have used [`calligra`](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/fundus/calligra/calligra.pdf) package and you can obtain the classic Computer Modern called CM (1st font default family) and `calligra` calligraphic font. You will obtain this result.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{calligra}
\begin{document}

Instead of my parents, I will have
\textcalligra{To my parents}
\end{document}
```

The second option, maybe you'll like it better is the following one, [ZAPF CHANCERY](https://www.tug.org/FontCatalogue/urwchancery/) with your font family called [`pzc`](https://books.google.it/books?id=S4CxDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA170&lpg=PA170&dq=%5Cusepackage%7Bchancery%7D&source=bl&ots=1zLpspe_Jr&sig=ACfU3U250ityGxNHezOjqnfH_QLPRhbfBA&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjGj8mGkp3nAhUCoqQKHbhLBD4Q6AEwAnoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%5Cusepackage%7Bchancery%7D&f=false). 
[image]

Here you will have this result.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\newcommand*\zapchan{\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
Instead of my parents, I will have
\zapchan{To my parents}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I add also a link of the calligraphic font in the site LaTeX Font Catalogue:
https://www.tug.org/FontCatalogue/calligraphicalfonts.html

Comment: There are a few different problems with this. The fonts aren’t scaled, and the `\zapchan` command is going to bleed out of the parentheses and change all the text after it.

Comment: Meanwhile thank you for your advice. Very kind Davislor have you seen the comment to the user? :-( I not what the check mark :-( I have not tried but the "my parents" should to stay at the end of a letter and not in line with the text. My was an example.

Answer (score 4):

### In the Modern Toolchain

This example uses TeX Gyre Chorus, which is a free clone of Zapf Chancery.  You can substitute any font of your choice.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase}
\newfontface\dedicationfont{TeXGyreChorus-MediumItalic}[Ligatures=Common]
\begin{document}

{\dedicationfont To my Parents}

\end{document}
```

[image: TeX Gyre Chorus sample]

### With Legacy Fonts

My advice is to use modern fonts when you can, and 8-bit legacy fonts when you have to.  If you have to, TeX Gyre Chorus is the family `qzc`.  You can look for others at [the LaTeX Font Catalogue](https://www.tug.org/FontCatalogue/calligraphicalfonts.html).

Here is a version compatible with PDFLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The default since 2018
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\newcommand\dedicationfont{\fontfamily{qzc}\itshape\mdseries\selectfont}

\begin{document}

{\dedicationfont To my Parents}

\end{document}
```

To be able to write something like `\textdedication{To my parents}`, add to the preamble

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textdedication}{\dedicationfont}
```

If you simply try to use `\newcommand*`, the formatting will bleed through and affect the following text.

Comment: Thank you @Davislor. Feeling blessed with "To my parents"!

Answer (score 1):

Hope this may helps you:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=12.5pt,DIV15,BCOR20mm,oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{eufrak}

\begin{document}

$\mathfrak{To\ my\ Parents}$

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

**Another method**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=12.5pt,DIV15,BCOR20mm,oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{yfonts}

\begin{document}

\textfrak{To\ my\ Parents}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Nothing says "I love you, parents" like mathematical Fraktur. But seriously: I think they are looking for a solution that makes it possible to use any possible font (and probably ones made for setting actual text, not mathematical expressions).

Comment: The "long s" is incorrect at the end of a word.  (It would also be very confusing in math, so I am suspicious of how `yfonts` is being used.  Any good fraktur font should have the "normal" s.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton The normal s is typed as `s:` (I think it's a ligature in the font). I also seem to remember that `yfonts` is tailored for metafont, while in a modern installation one should use the `oldgerm` package.

Comment: @campa -- Thanks for the details.  Yes, I'm pretty sure that `yfonts` is metafont-based, so essentially superseded.