# Font(Old English MT) other than normal font in thesis

Tags: fonts

[image: Old English style]

I want to write name of the university in this font style mentioned in the attached picture called as Old English MT. How can i do this. 
More over i am the following latex environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{report}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{paralist,pst-func, pst-plot, pst-math, pstricks-add,pgfplots}
%\usepackage{hang,hangindent=-.5cm}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\textwidth  5.8in \textheight 8.5 in \topmargin 0.0in \oddsidemargin
0.0in \evensidemargin 0.0in \setlength{\parindent}{12pt}
\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{ax}{Axiom}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem*{notation}{Notation}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Figure } % put Figure before the number
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{:}     % add colon after the number
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{1.3cm}     % extra space for extended numbers
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{Table } % put Table before the number
\renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnum}{:}     % add colon after the number
\addtolength{\cfttabnumwidth}{1.3cm}     % extra space for extended numbers
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\begin{document}
%\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}[roman page number from title]
\renewcommand{\thepage}{}
\vspace{3cm}
\begin{center}
\section*{\textbf{\Huge{Topic of thesis}}}
\end{center}
%\begin{figure}[htb] % Default value is [tbp]
%\begin{center}
%\epsfig{file=iub.eps, width=0.9 in}
%\end{center}
%\end{figure}
\begin{center}
By
\end{center}
\begin{center}
{\Large\bf{............}}\\ [2 cm]
\end{center}
\begin{center}
{\Large\bf{PhD Dissertation}}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
%\\ \quad
{\bf{Session year-year}}\\[3 cm]
{\Large\bf{Department of Subject}}\\
     {\Large\bf{This is the Name of University}}\\
      {\Large\bf{city, Country}}\\
      2020
\end{center}
\newpage
\begin{center}
\section*{\textbf{\Huge{Topic of thesis}}}
\end{center}
%\begin{figure}[htb] % Default value is [tbp]
%\begin{center}
%\epsfig{monogram=iub.eps, width=0.9 in}
%\end{center}
%\end{figure}
\begin{center}
By
\end{center}
\begin{center}
{\Large\bf{.............}}\\ [2 cm]
\end{center}
\begin{center}
Supervised By\\
{\large{\textbf{...............}}}\\[3 cm]

%\\ \quad
%{\bf{Session 2013-2016}}
{\Large\bf{Department of Subject}}\\
     {\Large\bf{This is the Name of University}}\\
      {\Large\bf{city, Country}}\\
      2020
\end{center}
\newpage

\begin{center}
\section*{\textbf{\Huge{Topic of thesis \\ [1 cm]}}}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
By \\ [1 cm]
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\textbf{..........} \\ [1 cm]
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\large{A dissertation submitted to the department of ..........\\
 This is the Name of University ,\\
 in the partial fulfillment for the degree of}\\
\end{center}
\begin{center}
{\Large\bf{Doctor of Philosophy}}\\
in\\
{\large{Subject}}\\
%{\large{June 2014}}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
Supervised By\\
{\large{\textbf{.............}}}\\ [2 cm]
\end{center}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\begin{center}
\section*{Student's Declaration}
\end{center}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Student's Declaration}{}
I,..............

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\begin{center}
\section*{Supervisor's Declaration}
\end{center}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Supervisor's Declaration}{}
It is hereby certified that work 
\newpage
\begin{center}
\section*{Certificate}
\end{center}
%\chapter*{Certificate}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Certificate}{}
It is hereby certified that work presented by ............
\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}{}
In this thesis, we present some flows of non Newtonian fluids with temperature dependent viscosity.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{center}
\section*{Acknowledgements}
\end{center}








\qquad\qquad \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
\textbf{............}

\newpage
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\begin{center}
%\section*{\underline{\textsl{Dedication}}}
%\end{center}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Dedication}{}
\qquad\\[4 Cm]
\qquad\qquad \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\ \textbf{To my mother, wife and kids}
\qquad\qquad \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\tableofcontents
%\newpage
%\listoftables
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}{}
%\listoffigures
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}{}
\newpage
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Preface%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter*{\begin{center}{Preface}\end{center}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Preface}{}

\newpage
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Contents}{}
\tableofcontents
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpage
\listoftables

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}{}

\newpage

\listoffigures

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}{}

\newpage
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\section*{List of Symbols}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Symbols}{}
%\begin{enumerate}
%\item $u$ shows the velocity component along x-axis
%\item $v$ shows the velocity component along y-axis
%\item $w$ shows the velocity component along z-axis
%%\item $A^{b}_{n}$, $H^{b}_{n}$, $S^{a}_{n,e}$ and $S^{a}_{n,o}$ are proposed subdivision schemes
%%\item $A_{n}(z)$ and $P_{n}(z)$ are Laurent polynomials of the subdivision schemes
%    \end{enumerate}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\newpage
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setcounter{page}{1}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}
 %\include{Chap_1}
 %\include{Chap_2}
% \include{Chap_3}
% \include{Chap_4}
% \include{Chap_5}
% \include{Chap_6}



\end{document}
```

Comment: You will find a large number of fonts here: https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/blackletterfonts.html

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! If you want this *exact* font, then you can buy it from the [Monotype website](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/old-english/)... And then either convert the font files to make them useable in LaTeX (which you maybe use, you didn't specify) or if you're using XeTeX or LuaLaTeX you can load it directly if it's on your system. Or you look for a font package you like here: https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/blackletterfonts.html

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25249/172164 ?

Comment: I an using latex. Downloading a font is not a problem actual problem is how to install that font. Guide simply how to install.

Comment: @ShahidRafiq it will probably be much easier to use one of the pre-packaged fonts from tug. If you really, really need to use Old English MT, then it will probably be easier to switch to using LuaLaTeX or XeTeX. But if you want to use this exact font with LaTeX you have to package it yourself. This will be a lot of work though, as far as I know you can do it using [LCDF](https://www.lcdf.org/type/) and [fontools](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/utilities/fontools/) (maybe also see [this package](https://www.ece.ucdavis.edu/~jowens/code/otfinst/)).

Comment: @ShahidRafiq I've also seen someone mention on this website that they have paid a professional (Ulrike Fischer from http://www.troubleshooting-tex.de/) to have a font properly packaged for them, because it can be quite a pain to do. Just giving you a fair warning `:)`

Comment: @Peter Wilson i have already asked this question.

Comment: Shahid Rafiq, if you have Microsoft Office installed, I can post an answer.

Comment: @Peter Wilson .....dear i have this font on my Microsoft word

Comment: @corporal ......i have this font in my Microsoft office.

Comment: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=33205

Comment: I really cannot understand your troubles. It was explained to you how to do it, you refused to try to understand because you lack the most basic understanding of what LaTeX is. Because of that, i told you to use a screenshot, which is the most dimple thing to do and takes less than 5 minutes. Yet still, you keep this problem busy in two different sites, without proper crosslinks. This is not how you treat people trying to help you.

Comment: To make it simple: you cannot use the font with what you call latex. Use a screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

The OP has indicated in comments that Microsoft Office is installed, the desired Old English font is named `Old English Text MT` and it is included with Microsoft Office.

```
% Compile using XeLaTeX
% Name the file university.tex % for example
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Old English Text MT}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{24pt}{28.8pt}\selectfont This is the name of university
\end{document}
```

This will produce a cropped pdf which you can include using \includegraphics.
The font size is 24pt, which you can set to any reasonable value you like. If the `graphicx` package is loaded, the pdf image can be inserted by `\includegraphics{university}`

Comment: ...i m receiving error. of undefined control sequence. when itried to compile in XeLatex.  I am unable to run other like XeLatex etc. kindly guide me just in Latex because i have a very short time for my thesis

Comment: @ShahidRafiq -- This suggestion, to create a small pdf file containing only the name of the university, using XeTeX, and then including it as a graphic, is the quickest possible solution, since trying to use this font with just basic `pdflatex` would require repackaging the font.  That would take quite a bit of time, as well as special expertise.

Comment: @ShahidRafiq the standalone file above does work, maybe you used XeTeX not XeLaTeX to compile. What was the undefined control sequence? Please try again. From your sample file below, it seems you want an eps image, not a pdf image. To convert a pdf image to eps use the command line: `pdftops -eps filename.pdf`

Comment: Right now i think the quickest end to this ordeal is to send shahid a cropped pdf via mail. :-\

Answer (score 2):

### In PDFTeX

My recommendation is to use a modern engine and Unicode when you can, and legacy fonts when you have to.  (Although not everyone agrees.)  In this case, you say you have to.

Pick a blackletter font you like from [the LaTeX Font Catalogue](https://www.tug.org/FontCatalogue/blackletterfonts.html), and that’s available from CTAN **in Type 1** format.

For example, [Gotik](https://www.tug.org/FontCatalogue/gotik/) should work.  If your TeX Live installation doesn’t come with it, install the `gothic` package with `tlmgr`.

Then, you can follow the instructions on the page to activate it:

```
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

and in the document:

```
{\gothfamily Some University Somewhere}
```

You could also add a command to the preamble:

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textgoth}{\gothfamily}
```

which would let you write

```
\textgoth{Some University Somewhere}
```

### Example

Based on the first page of your source, with somewhat-modernized LaTeX:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The default since 2018
\usepackage{tgpagella, newpxmath} % A successor to mathpazo
\usepackage{yfonts} % For gothic

\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textgoth}{\gothfamily}

\begin{document}

  \begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    {\Huge\bfseries\scshape Topic of Thesis}\\
    {\bfseries\Large By ......}\\
    {\bfseries Session year--year}\\% en dash!
    {\bfseries\Large Department of Subject}\\
    {\bfseries\Large\gothfamily Some University Somewhere}\\
    {\bfseries\Large City, Country}
  \end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image: Gothik/Pagella sample]

### In LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX

You can load this font with `\newfontface` [like in this answer,](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525476/how-can-we-change-the-font-type-for-a-line-in-latex/525492#525492) replacing the name of the font with the one you need.  For example:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\almamater{Old English MT}
```

You might want to check out which font features the font supports with `otfinfo`.  For example, if it supports `DFLT` ligatures, you can add the option `[Ligatures = Common]`.

Then you can write

```
{\almamater Some University}
```

You can also define

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textalmamater}{\almamater}
```

to be able to write

```
\textalmamater{Some University}
```

Comment: i am using latex. I am unable to run other like XeLatex etc. kindly guide me just in Latex because i have a very short time for my thesis

Comment: @ShahidRafiq Added a version that ought to work in PDFLaTeX (warning: untested).

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting another answer because it's quite different to the other answers.

Currently other answers to this question suggest using `XeLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX` to get the desired Old English font, or `pdfLaTeX` to use a substitute font. This answer suggest two methods which rely on Microsoft Word to generate a suitable pdf, and then use standard packages or tools to obtain the desired result.

**Method 1:** Use Microsoft Word to create the single title page with the desired fonts, layout and spacing. Then use the `save as Adobe PDF` option from Word.
Include the pdf using the `pdfpages` package using the command `\includepdf{filename}`

**Method 2:** If the page needs to be included as an `eps` graphic, then use Microsoft Word to create a custom sized page the same area as the thesis main file type area: width 5.8in and height 8.5 in. Use the desired fonts to create the title page. Then use the `save as Adobe PDF` option from word.
Now use the command line: `pdftops -eps filename.pdf`
Finally include the title page using `\noindent\includegraphics{filename}`

Some extra info for using Microsoft Word to (approximately) match the LaTeX font sizes, source `The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2e`

The thesis is using `12pt` option, the matching fontsizes are as follows.

```
\normalsize 12pt
\large 14pt
\Large 17pt
\LARGE 20pt
\huge25pt
\Huge 25pt
```